# Excel: search cell with comma separated values ignoring spaces

Tags: excel, if-statement, search

I have a comma separated value in an excel cell `AB, CD`. There are two columns `A B` and `C D`. Now I want to search the cells to check if the comma separated value appears and if it does it would write `OK` or `Not OK` under the columns. It should ignore the spaces and while searching `AB` it should write `OK` under `A B`.

I tried the following formula and it works but does not ignore spaces. So it does not match `AB` to A B`. Any pointers?

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("AB",K2)),"OK","Not OK")`

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace any spaces in K2 with an empty string:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("AB",SUBSTITUTE(K2," ",""))),"OK","Not OK")
```

Comment: Can you explain the formula?

Comment: The part I added - SUBSTITUTE(K2," ","") - replaces all space-characters (ASCII-code 32) with an empty string. If you have a cell K2 containing " A B , CC, YY", the result will be "AB,CC,YY". The next part of your formula will then be evaluated as: SEARCH("AB", "AB,CC,YY"), which will result in a match and return a number (1), which in turn makes ISNUMBER(1) return TRUE ...

Comment: @Sarah, did my answer help you?